# Is there an issue doing EFA first, followed by a cluster analysis (with the newly found factors) with the same sample?

Tags: clustering, methodology, exploratory-data-analysis

We want to compute a cluster analysis in a not well-researched field and therefore created about 60 questions. Those questions are supposedly aspects of factors, but we are not sure yet, to which extent. But our primary purpose is to analyse the object structure of the sample. Not only since 60 variables are far too many for our sample size, we would like to compute an EFA first and then use the same sample for a cluster analysis using the newly found factors.

I thought a lot about the implications of using the same sample twice but can't find a problem here, since both approaches are not dependent on each other. I think they complement each other well. The EFA leads to a reduction in details.

But maybe I don't see a crucial aspect here.

Edit: I Rewrote the title to have EFA more prominent.

Comment: Papers loosely similar were once common in fields I know. People pushing PCA results through a cluster analysis is still standard in some other fields I know. I think the issue is likely to be mostly whether your research is thought helpful in the present state of the art by reviewers for journals, or whoever is evaluating your work. I don't see a statistical problem here beyond  differing views of the utility of EFA, which may or may not bite at your review stage. (To be less cryptic, this kind of approach peaked around 1970 in geography and related Earth sciences.)

Comment: I am picking up a flavour of people being asked questions about their (who knows except you?) attributes, attitudes, behaviour. If so, do you think that people really fall into distinct groups as compared with varying on a continuum? I gather that marketing people still find that a helpful framework.

Comment: @NickCox We are evaluating if there are distinct groups in traffic behaviour to decide if certain problematic behaviour needs special attention considering prevention efforts.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks a lot. This is very helpful.